# CSS Left Center a tag button

Tags: css, center

I would like to Center Left this button...reading code examples it does not center. How to center it using css so when the user open page in web browser that button center left automatically on user resolution.

Here is code example:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
<a class="button">Click Me</a>
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrapper {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.button {
    color: white;
    letter-spacing: -2px;
    padding: 20px;
    display: block;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #145982;
    font-family: 'Myriad Pro',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 80px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    width: 350px;
    border: 1px solid #60b4e5;
    margin: 60px auto;
    background-color: #59aada;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#5eb2e2, #4f9cca);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#5eb2e2), to(#4f9cca));
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
}
```

[**my Code Sample**](http://jsfiddle.net/babY6/)

Comment: include relevant code here.. Dont just put fiddle.

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/babY6/3/

Comment: yes this is what i need ...thanks Vikas Ghodke.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it wasn't centering with `text-align: center` on the parent, is because you had `.button` as `display: block`. A child element with display block does not obey text-align center from the parent. But a display of inline-block, static, or inline does.

```
.button {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/babY6/1/)

Comment: Thank You for answer...i need this.... http://postimg.org/image/czftu0qtf/    to center it on the screen and then put it left

Answer (score 1):

You are using position:absolute; that`s the reason of the problem, remove it and your button will be centered.

Comment: can you please post fiddle link with modification you mentioned? i try to add margin-top and remove position absolute but it is now top centered not left centered. Many Thanks

Comment: Please http://jsfiddle.net/babY6/4/
You can change float to left, right or center to move your button

Comment: This is what i need: http://jsfiddle.net/babY6/3/ solution that gives Vikas Ghodke. Thanks to others for helping and giving solutions.